# multiple codes in a cell to convert to text

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, office365, find-and-replace

I have a cell which contains multiples codes that are pipe delimited - up to 5 codes. Additionally, I have a decoder for the codes on a separate excel sheet. I basically want to replace the codes with the text  in the pipe delimited cell
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mi0Qw.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUaH7.png)

Comment: How do you want this to be accomplish this, what have your tried so far, and where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What have you done so far to achieve this goal? This site is not a free scripting service. The community here helps those who help themselves. So if you have attempted to do something to achieve this goal, please post your code/script/formula and the community can attempt to help you. As it stands this question reads as a free scripting request and will most likely be closed as a result.

Comment: Do you mean you want to return the data with the symbol ｜for the result?

Answer (score 1):

You listed O365 so I will assume you have access to that--this is way, way easier in O365 than earlier versions.

Assume the code(s) you want to decode are in A1.  Assume your code translation table is in E1:F20.

We're going to:

1. Split your code string into a horizontal *array* of codes using TEXTSPLIT().  AA|BB|CC would become an array: {"AA","BB","CC"}.
2. We're going to step through that array by column using BYCOL with a LAMBDA that looks up each code in the code table.  So now we have an *array* of full text descriptions.
3. Then we'll glue them back together in a single cell delimited by "|".

We'll place this formula in B1, next to the first code:

`=TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,BYCOL(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"|"),LAMBDA(c,XLOOKUP(c,$E$1:$E$20,$F$1:$F$20))))`

Then copy down.